# Adding email as attachment from Outlook to Access table

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I've setup a simple process in Outlook VBA when an email comes in it will grab the Sender, Subject, Body and received time from the email and dump it into a table (ITtbl) in access. The problem I'm having is I want it to also want to attach the entire email as an attachment in the access table.

The access table has a field called "Attachment" that is also setup as attachment format.
The problem is I'm getting an "Object variable or with block variable not set" error on the `Mattach = MyMail.attachments` line. I'm also thinking I don't have the correct syntax in my Insert line.

I've done some research but everything I've found is excel based for saves and not access.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
'On Error Resume Next

'Mail Definitions
Dim MyMail As MailItem
Set MyMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)

Dim MSub As String, MSender As String, MBody As String, Mtime As Date, Mattach As Attachment

MSub = MyMail.Subject
MSender = MyMail.Sender
MBody = MyMail.Body
Mtime = MyMail.ReceivedTime
Mattach = MyMail.attachments

If MyMail.Subject = "*Proof*" Then
'INSERT Query
Dim str As String
str = "INSERT INTO ITtbl ([From], [Subject], [Body], [Received], [Attachment]) VALUES (" & "'" & MSender & "'" & ", " & "'" & MSub & "'" & ", " & "'" & MBody & "'" & ", " & "'" & Mtime & "'" & ", " & Mattach & ")"

'Access Connection
Dim cnx As ADODB.Connection
Set cnx = New ADODB.Connection

cnx.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
cnx.ConnectionString = "\\page\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\CID Database\Test Database\dbBE\CID_be.accdb"
cnx.Open
cnx.Execute str

Else
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @niton I attempted to use this method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add). But I want the email itself as the attachment. This method uses a file in a location as the attachment and I'm not sure of the syntax for adding an attachment to insert into with this method.

Comment: You need to save the item to the disk where you could read it as a byte array and put to the Access Db. See my post for more information on that.

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.attachments) property returns returns an `Attachments` object that represents all the attachments for the specified item.

```
Mattach = MyMail.attachments
```

If you need to get attached files you can iterate over all entries in the `Attachments` collection and call the [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method which saves the attachment to the specified path on the disk. Then you can read the bytes array from the disk and insert that data to the Access table. For example, the following code sample shows to handle attached files:

```
Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
'Prompt the user for confirmation 
Dim strPrompt As String 
strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder, it will be overwritten with this copy of the file." 
 
If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
  myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & _ 
  myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName 
End If
```

And, if you need to put the source item into the table, you need to save it on the disk first by using the [MailItem.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) method and then reading the byte array from there.

Comment: Okay so there is no easy way to do it with the insert into, I'd have to do a saveasfile to the disk and then use that as the attachment? just making sure I understand.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right avenue, need to save an item the disk to be able to read the content as a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the whole message (attachments and all) in the database, there is no reason to deal with the separate attachments - just save the whole message as an MSG file using `MyMail.SaveAs("c:\temp\message.msg", olMsgUnicode)`, then read file contents into a blob.